# Recursive java function to repeat the beginning and end of the word "computing"

Tags: java, recursion

**I can not use global variables, helper methods or any loops**
 **Not interested in answer, but guidance would be great.**

Currently console is printing:

#### compcompcompcomputingtingtingting

but it needs to be:

> computing
> compcomputingting
> compcompcomputingtingting
> compcompcompcomputingtingting

```
public static String madComputing(int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return "Must be postive integer";// printing to present error instead getting error in console
    if (n > 1000)// avoid overflow
        return "Cannot be greater than 1000";

    if (n > 0) {
        //System.out.print("computing");
        return "comp" + madComputing(n - 1) + "ting" ;
    } else
        return "u";
}
```

Comment: I think I know where you're going with this... but can you clarify a bit further? While I was using debug it would not print to console until it was all over and print at once.. So i have to figure out how to print at each step?

Comment: Also, I shoud specify I can not change the method signature, so I were to return System.out.print something it would have to be void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain this to you rather than give you the quick answer. It looks like you have the base cases all correct and your issue can be fixed with a few small tweaks:

I think the primary problem with your code is that you're not printing / creating a new output at every recursive call - your recursive calls are simply appending to the same string each time. You can tell you need to print something at each recursive call because your ideal output doesn't just show the final string but also the increments in between.

So in each recursive call, you'll print your result so far, and then pass that intermediate result to the next recursive call. This means your method needs to take a parameter (or 2) which will be the result so far (accumulator)

Now the question is, what does the intermediate result look like? This will be the the thing that changes between each output, which is the 'comp's before 'u' and the 'tings' after. So you can pass an a 'before' and 'after' string parameters (which will be empty strings on the first call) that hold the string of 'comp's and 'ting's so far.

Then on each call, you just need to add a 'comp' to the before string, a 'ting' to the after string, print the whole thing with a 'u' in the middle (before + 'u' + after) and then pass the *new* before and after strings to the recursive call

**Edit after further clarification: doing it without an accumulator**:

If you need to accomplish this without an accumulator, it's a little more complex:

1. The base case needs to be "computing" instead of "u"
2. For the non-base case, first make the recursive call (i.e. call the method with n-1) and store it as a string (say `recc_result`)
3. Split the recursive result by newline `\n` and get the last line out of it. This can be done using `recc_result.split()` and then taking the last element of the array. Call this `last_line`
4. Finally, return the `recc_result + '\n' + 'comp' + last_line + 'ting'`

Explanation:

The change of base case is because you want to print "computing" when n=1 and not just "u".

And the way to thing about the rest is that on each stage, you're taking the last line from the result so far and adding a 'comp' to the front and a 'ting' to the end, then attaching this to the result.

So the base case is 'computing'. Then for n=2, we get the recursive result for n-1 (which is 1) which will give us 'computing'. The last line from this result is the only line (i.e. 'computing'). Then we add a 'comp' and a 'ting' and attach it to the whole result giving us "computing\ncompcomputingting".

For n=3, the recc_result is "computing\ncompcomputingting" from which we take the last line ("compcomputingting") and then add a comp and ting making "compcompcomputingtingting" and attach it to the whole result giving "computing\ncompcomputingting\ncompcompcomputingtingting"

Note: `\n` = newline

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, I'll try to work something out that is similar without changing the method itself. I.e has to return a String and can only take one parameter.

Comment: ah okay. I added to my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra parameter as the accumulator and give the initial param as "computing".
Call it as madComputing(4, "computing") for your example case.

It looks very bad code wise but it still does the job:

```
public static String madComputing(int n, String acc) {
  if (n < 0) {
      return "Must be postive integer";
  }
  if (n > 1000) {
      return "Cannot be greater than 1000"; 
  }   
  if (n > 0) {
      System.out.println(acc);
      acc = "comp" + acc + "ting";
      return madComputing(n - 1, acc);
  } else {
    return ""; 
  }  
}
```

Or if you can not add an accumulator:

```
public static String madComputing(int n) {
  if (n < 0) {
      return "Must be postive integer";
  }
  if (n > 1000) {
      return "Cannot be greater than 1000"; 
  }   
  if (n >= 0) {
      String value = "comp" + (n == 0 ? "u" : madComputing(n - 1))+ "ting";
      System.out.println(value);      
      return value;
  } 
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort you made to post the answer, but I am not interested in that. I'd appreciate it if you could delete this as it does not help me.

Comment: @Onhel As a general principle, Stack Overflow is a resource for future visitors who have the same problem as you. If an answer doesn't help you, just ignore it instead of asking the author to delete it. It could be useful to someone else. You can also consider pointing out why it doesn't solve the problem and the answerer may be willing to edit it to meet your needs. You might also want to edit your post to state that you can't change the method header. I recommend taking the [tour] to help familiarize yourself with the site.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll keep that in mind going forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String madComputing(int n) {
    String res = "";
    String half = "";
    if (n < 0)
        return "Has to be positive";
    if (n > 1000)
        return "Stackoverflow for values greater than 999";
    if (n > 1) {// anything larger than 1
        res = "" + madComputing(n - 1);// assign the recursive call to var res to split and access it's substring
        // System.out.println(res); if you leave this in, it will print at each level
        half = res.substring(res.lastIndexOf("\n") + 1);// get the last indexed value
        return "comp" + half + "ting";// use half to complete my method which will print for any n less than 1000
    } else {
        return "computing";// this is the base case when n == 1
    }

}
```